# use Dictionary<int,List<obj>> or simple,single large Collection<obj> for fetching in large List collection

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, observablecollection

My current implementation is I have large number of objects in my collection. Items are inserted only once i.e at start up.

And then this list is used for searching and fetching objects from it.

Each object is is assigned to particular type having `int` value.

e.g In a list of 100 items of ice-cream objects, 20 belong to vanilla category, 25 belong to mango and so on. Categories have unique `int` identifier.

Should I replace current implementation with `Dictionary<int,List<ice-cream>>` for better performance?

Comment: Would you ever need to find all the "ice-creams", all "vanillas"...? If yes use `Dictionary`. Else simply use the big collection - not much performance gain then.

Comment: yes. I would need to find & retrieve all ice-cream objects of type vanilla,mango etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance aside (100 items are peanuts);

I think your code should reflect what your intentions are. If you intend to treat these objects as a list, then you should have a list. But as you are performing lookup based on id, you should have a Dictionary.

And you should wrap this dictionary in a (static/singleton) class and not pass this dictionary  around all willy nilly. Especially if you require thread safety.

Answer (score 1):

If you can identify for you program finit set of keys that user will execute search over data, use of `Dictionary<..>` is a way to go.

It's hard to suggest something real, as the notion of a data collection it too vaugue.